# Correct name format for Bundle subfolders in ZIP file?

Tags: blackberry, release, blackberry-playbook, blackberry-world

i'm new in BB development.

I need to make a ZIP file for the release of the app on vendor portal. I'm reading this: https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/appworld/preparing_your_zip_file.html#pde1350481571678

I have problems to understand name format for Bundle subfolders in ZIP file...

> The name of the bundle subfolder specifies the earliest version of the
>   operating system that the bundle supports. The name must use the
>   following format: bundle_name_x.x.x.x, where x.x.x.x represents the
>   version of the BlackBerry Device Software or BlackBerry PlayBook OS.

My app must target BlackBerry PlayBook OS 2.0 (or later). So what i should put as name of the subfolder??  BlackBerry_PlayBook_OS_2.0.0.0 ???

Thanks

Comment: you can directly add file bundles. no need to make a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, use BlackBerry_PlayBook_OS_2.0.0.0 to target PlayBook OS 2.0 or later.

The reason for this format, is so you as the vendor have amazing control over which platforms you target.  Say there is an OS bug affecting your app that is occurring in PlayBook OS 2.0.0.1.

If you wanted to ensure that only users with supported OS' can download your app, you could create a folder named BlackBerry_PlayBook_OS_2.0.0.2